# Add digits to the left of a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame of pandas in Python:

| ID | code | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14563 | red |
| 1 | 4563 | blue |
| 2 | 1463 | green |
| 3 | 82930 | red |
| 4 | 903 | green |
| 5 | 18392 | red |

For the `code` column, I want that if the value has 4 digits or less, fill in with leading zeros until they have five digits.

| ID | code | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 14563 | red |
| 1 | 04563 | blue |
| 2 | 01463 | green |
| 3 | 82930 | red |
| 4 | 00903 | green |
| 5 | 18392 | red |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df['code'] = df['code'].str.zfill(5)
```

check: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

you can add astype(str) if the code column is int and not str like:

```
 df['code'] = df['code'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```